# pandas: FloatingPointError with np.seterr(all='raise') and missing data

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, anaconda

I'm getting a FloatingPointError when I want to look at data involving missing data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.seterr(all='raise')

s = pd.Series([np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],index=[1,2,3]); print(s); print(s.head())
```

I'm on the newest version of `pandas`, installed via

```
conda install -f pandas
```

after `pkill python` and `conda remove pandas`.

Here's the trace back:

```
Out[4]: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FloatingPointError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/xxx/.conda/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.pyc in __call__(self, obj)
    695                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    696                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 697             printer.pretty(obj)
    698             printer.flush()
    699             return stream.getvalue()

/home/xxx/.conda/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.pyc in pretty(self, obj)
    381                             if callable(meth):
    382                                 return meth(obj, self, cycle)
--> 383             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    384         finally:
    385             self.end_group()

/home/xxx/.conda/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.pyc in _default_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    501     if _safe_getattr(klass, '__repr__', None) not in _baseclass_reprs:
    502         # A user-provided repr. Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 503         _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    504         return
    505     p.begin_group(1, '<')

/home/xxx/.conda/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/lib/pretty.pyc in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    683     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
    684     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 685     output = repr(obj)
    686     for idx,output_line in enumerate(output.splitlines()):
    687         if idx:

/home/xxx/.conda/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.pyc in __repr__(self)
     61         Yields Bytestring in Py2, Unicode String in py3.
     62         """
---> 63         return str(self)
     64 
     65 

/home/xxx/.conda/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.pyc in __str__(self)
     41         if compat.PY3:
     42             return self.__unicode__()
---> 43         return self.__bytes__()
     44 
     45     def __bytes__(self):

/home/xxx/.conda/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.pyc in __bytes__(self)
     53 
     54         encoding = get_option("display.encoding")
---> 55         return self.__unicode__().encode(encoding, 'replace')
     56 
     57     def __repr__(self):

/home/xxx/.conda/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in __unicode__(self)
    954 
    955         self.to_string(buf=buf, name=self.name, dtype=self.dtype,
--> 956                        max_rows=max_rows)
    957         result = buf.getvalue()
    958 

/home/xxx/.conda/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in to_string(self, buf, na_rep, float_format, header, length, dtype, name, max_rows)
    992         the_repr = self._get_repr(float_format=float_format, na_rep=na_rep,
    993                                   header=header, length=length, dtype=dtype,
--> 994                                   name=name, max_rows=max_rows)
    995 
    996         # catch contract violations

/home/xxx/.conda/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in _get_repr(self, name, header, length, dtype, na_rep, float_format, max_rows)
   1022                                         float_format=float_format,
   1023                                         max_rows=max_rows)
-> 1024         result = formatter.to_string()
   1025 
   1026         # TODO: following check prob. not neces.

/home/xxx/.conda/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.pyc in to_string(self)
    223 
    224         fmt_index, have_header = self._get_formatted_index()
--> 225         fmt_values = self._get_formatted_values()
    226 
    227         maxlen = max(self.adj.len(x) for x in fmt_index)  # max index len

/home/xxx/.conda/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.pyc in _get_formatted_values(self)
    213         return format_array(self.tr_series._values, None,
    214                             float_format=self.float_format,
--> 215                             na_rep=self.na_rep)
    216 
    217     def to_string(self):

/home/xxx/.conda/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.pyc in format_array(values, formatter, float_format, na_rep, digits, space, justify)
   1974                         justify=justify)
   1975 
-> 1976     return fmt_obj.get_result()
   1977 
   1978 

/home/xxx/.conda/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.pyc in get_result(self)
   1990 
   1991     def get_result(self):
-> 1992         fmt_values = self._format_strings()
   1993         return _make_fixed_width(fmt_values, self.justify)
   1994 

/home/xxx/.conda/envs/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.pyc in _format_strings(self)
   2085 
   2086             # this is pretty arbitrary for now
-> 2087             has_large_values = (abs_vals > 1e8).any()
   2088             has_small_values = ((abs_vals < 10 ** (-self.digits)) &
   2089                                 (abs_vals > 0)).any()

FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in greater
```

Comment: Weird: `np.array([np.nan]) > 1e8` gives me `array([False], dtype=bool)`, but `np.array([np.nan, np.nan]) > 1e8` raises.  Must take a different branch if there's only one element.

Comment: Well, I've created an issue at both `pandas` and `numpy`, let's see what happens. I guess for now I need to turn off `seterr()`. Shudder. How do people sleep at night when apparently *everyone* is ignoring these FloatingPointErrors by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you `import pandas`, all numpy errors are set to be ignore. This is currently undocumented behavior.

This is done in [pandas/compat/numpy_compat.py](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/compat/numpy_compat.py)

```
# TODO: HACK for NumPy 1.5.1 to suppress warnings
# is this necessary?
try:
    np.seterr(all='ignore')
except Exception:  # pragma: no cover
    pass
```

Here's how that plays out

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.geterr()
Out[2]: {'divide': 'warn', 'invalid': 'warn', 'over': 'warn', 'under': 'ignore'}

In [3]: import pandas as pd

In [4]: np.geterr()
Out[4]: {'divide': 'ignore', 'invalid': 'ignore', 'over': 'ignore', 'under': 'ignore'}

In [5]: s = pd.Series([np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],index=[1,2,3]); print(s); print(s.head())
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
dtype: float64
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
dtype: float64

In [6]: np.seterr(invalid='raise')
Out[6]: {'divide': 'ignore', 'invalid': 'ignore', 'over': 'ignore', 'under': 'ignore'}
In [7]: s = pd.Series([np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],index=[1,2,3]); print(s); print(s.head())
FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in greater
```

The "solution" is hence to not `np.seterr(invalid'raise')`, whenever you use `pandas` (especially when working with missing data).